# SplashScreen like Gmail

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

I want to show a SplashScreen as Gmail. that is, show the ActionBar and load all data from my main screen procedurally

I've tested it on an application blank and first show a black screen then load my design

This is my code SplashScreen for the application blank.

```
[Activity(
    Label = "SampleQuickApp.Droid"
    , MainLauncher = true
    , Icon = "@drawable/icon"
    , Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash"
    , NoHistory = true
    , ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class SplashScreen : MvxSplashScreenActivity
{
    public SplashScreen()
        : base(Resource.Layout.FirstView)
    {
    }
```

How avoid this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're looking for? I launched the Gmail app on both my Nexus 4 and my Nexus 5 and was unable to see a splashscreen at all. It took me directly into my list of messages.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell, Gmail app doesn't SplashScreen. You see the main view of the app, cleanly and later load all the info. That I mean with SplashScreen.

When I develop a App in Mvx I don't have this behaviour.

Comment: yeah, the idea is that you can remove the splash screen. Try loading the data that you want to see right away into [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Comment: I believe the Gmail splashscreen is simply an image (or simple layout) that contains a blank ActionBar. Once the main Activity starts, there's a seamless transition, so it doesn't look like there's a splashscreen at all. Here's a screenshot http://imgur.com/dnob54S